# Protractor cucumber Typescript - Unable to create new service: internetexplorerdriverservice

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I'm getting the following error message when I try to launch via IE
"Unable to create new service: internetexplorerdriverservice"

Please find the details below:
(Protractor+cucumber+Typescript)

Node Version: `6.11.3'
Protractor Version: 5.1.2
Browser(s): IE 11
Operating System and Version Windows 7

When I tried with Chrome I'm getting error message "chormedriver.storage.googleapi.com udefined error.

Please can you suggest what is going wrong here?